# Using windows domain account instead of web server process identity for windows authentication using PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, pdo

I have been trying to connect to a MSSQL database under windows authentication using the PHP PDO library. I have read this documentation [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296205(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296205%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and have achieved a connection under the process name for the web server running my PHP code. However I was wondering if it was possible to use the windows credentials of the user logged into the machine running the web server instead of the machine itself?

Comment: what good would this to? A server is generally not going to have anyone logged into it, and the webserver app itself running under a specific ID.

Comment: The plan is to user the task scheduler in windows to run this connection periodically to extract data. You can specify the user the task will run under when setting it up.

Comment: I'm working under constraints imposed on me by the DB admin, they don't want to add the machine as a user to the sql server if it's possible to add a 'normal' user account instead.

Comment: Might be related to this domain identity issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761596/sql-integrated-security-using-computer-name-instead-of-user-name

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167369/windows-user-impersonation-in-php